# Argument pass to file read in as 0

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I have a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "You chose $1 and $2 "
if [[ $1 -eq 0 || $2 -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "You didn't chose argument"
  exit 1
elif 

...
exit 0
```

and in terminal I tried :

```
./Path/to/script argument1 argument2
```

In result I get:

```
You chose argument1 and argument2
You didn't chose argument
```

How it is possible that i the same moment it can return both arguments correct and see them them as 0?

What is wrong here?

Comment: Note that the condition is a bit shaky, and better be expressed with '&&' instead of '||'.

Comment: You are comparing strings to a number. Instead use  if [[ -z $1 .. etc.

Comment: `if (( $# < 2 )); then ...` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-eq` is for *integer* comparison, and `[[` gets a little funny when you try to compare a string to an integer. What happens is that `bash` treats that `$1` expands to as the name of *another* variable and expands *that*. If the variable does not exist, it expands to 0 by default.

If you want to check if the string itself is zero, stick with string comparison:

```
if [[ $1 = 0 || $2 = 0 ]]; then
```

If, as seems more likely you want to check if two arguments were actually provided, check the value of `$#` as suggested by mickp:

```
if (( $# < 2 )); then
  echo "You didn't provide 2 arguments.
```

Another option is to use the `${...?....}` form of parameter expansion, which prints a given error message and exits if the parameter is not set.

```
: ${1?You need two arguments, provided none}
: ${2?You need two arguments, provided only $1}
```

Comment: if (( $# < 2 )) it is exactly what I am looking for, thank you